# Gulp "no command gulp found". PATH changed

Tags: gulp

I got my one website on WordPress and had no code at all to be written myself. And now I decided to move one, write my own website, but stuck with some issues with Gulp after installing ("no command 'gulp' found") The most common reason met for Windows is the wrong PATH, and I've changed it. Any other thoughts? That's supposed to be just a starter kit for an auto page reload when HTML, CSS, JS is changed.

Answer (score 0):

this sounds like you only have gulp installed inside your current project.

First Solution:

Simply install `gulp-cli` globally. This will allow you to use `gulp` command

note: `gulp` still need to be installed per project basis.

```sh
npm install -g gulp-cli
```

Second Solution:

in case you don't want to install `gulp-cli` globally, you can add it as your `build` script inside your package.json. And then you can run `npm run build` from your terminal.

```json
{
  "script": {
    "build": "gulp"
  }
}
```